# Proof of Weierstrass approximation theorem

Tags: analysis, soft-question, weierstrass-approximation

I would like to know the proof of the Weierstrass approximation theorem.

I prefer proof that the story is easy to follow and requires little prior knowledge, but that is somewhat subjective, so I would like to know the various proofs <s>by asking a big-list question</s> (that tag was removed).

Bibliographic information or a summary is sufficient, not the full text of the proof.

Comment: Let $f:[0,1]\to\Bbb R$ be continuous. Extend $f$ to a continuous $f:[0,2\pi]$ with $f(0)=f(2\pi).$ Let $\sum_{j\ge 0}(A_j\cos jx+B_j\sin jx)$ be the Fourier series for $f.$ Let $f_n(x)=\sum_{j=0}^n(A_j\cos jx+B_j\sin jx).$ Let $g_m(x)=\frac {1}{m+1}\sum_{n=0}^m f_n(x).$ Theorem (Fejer): $g_m\to f$ uniformly as $m\to\infty$. Now each term in any $g_m$ can be uniformly approximated on $[0,1]$ by a finite portion of its power series, giving the Weierstrass Theorem for $f:[0,1]\to\Bbb R$... (continued)

Comment: ...(continued). The Fejer Theorem is surprisingly elementary to prove using the basic methods of Fourier series.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a proof for the **Weierstrass Approximation Theorem**:

Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function on a closed interval $[a, b]$. Then, for any $ε > 0$, there exists a polynomial $p(x)$ such that:

$|f(x) - p(x)|$ $<$ $ε$ for all $x$ in $[a, b]$.

**Proof**:

Since $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a, b]$, it is uniformly continuous. This means that for any $ε > 0$, there exists a positive number $δ$ such that $|f(x) - f(y)| < ε$ whenever $|x - y| < δ$.

Let's choose a finite set of points ${x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n}$ in $[a, b]$ such that the intervals $(x_i - δ, x_i + δ)$ for $i = 1, 2,\ldots, n$ cover $[a, b]$. We can do this by dividing [a, b] into subintervals of length $2δ$, and choosing one $x_i$ from each subinterval.

Next, we will use these points to construct a polynomial $p(x)$ that approximates $f(x)$. We use the Lagrange Interpolating Polynomial, which is a polynomial of degree at most $n - 1$ that passes through $n$ points. Specifically, let the Lagrange Interpolating Polynomial through the points $(x_i, f(x_i))$ be given by

$p(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)  l_i(x)$

where $l_i(x)$ is the $i-th$ Lagrange basis polynomial, defined as:

$l_i(x) = \prod_{j=1}^n (x - x_j) / (x_i - x_j)$ for $i ≠ j$

$l_i(x) = 1$ for $i = j$

By construction, $p(x)$ passes through the points $(x_i, f(x_i))$, so

$|f(x_i) - p(x_i)| = 0$ for all $i = 1, 2, \ldots, n$

By the triangle inequality,

$|f(x) - p(x)| \leq \sum_{i=1}^n |f(x) - f(x_i)|  |l_i(x)|$

Since $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $[a, b]$, and each $l_i(x)$ is continuous on $[a, b]$, it follows that $|f(x) - p(x)| < ε$ for all $x$ in $[a, b]$.

This completes the proof. The Weierstrass Approximation Theorem states that any continuous function on a closed interval can be arbitrarily closely approximated by a polynomial.

Comment: Could you please explain how you used the triangle inequality?

Comment: The author of this proof used the triangle inequality to establish a bound on the difference between the function $f(x)$ and the polynomial $p(x)$. More specifically, the upper bound on the error between the function and the polynomial.

Comment: “it follows that”? How?

Comment: There is no reason to think that the interpolating polynomial stays close to $f$ in between the points you have chosen to interpolate.  In fact, the Lagrange interpolation is quite bad at this.

Comment: Weierstrass Approximation Theorem states that any continuous function on a closed and bounded interval can be approximated arbitrarily closely by a polynomial function. The proof uses the fact ("follows") that the difference between the continuous function $f(x)$ and its approximation $p(x)$ can be bounded by a series (see above) involving the difference between $f(x)$ and its evaluation at discrete points $x_i$, multiplied by the continuous weighting factors $l_i(x)$.